# Running Powerpoint macros during a presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm new in VBA Powerpoint.  I wrote a macro (This macro reads out-loud the content of a textbox in active slide). I want this macro executed when I go to next slide while I am making a live powerpoint presentation.  How can I ensure this macro run when I `click` for the next-slide?

Comment: Please add any code that you have tried

Comment: Why not use the normal method to play a sound when a slide emerges? No Macro needed: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/play-music-or-other-sounds-automatically-when-a-slide-appears-9a717c28-5365-4ee7-9515-c1d043bc7101

Answer (score 0):

The events aren't easy to find in Powerpoint, but [this document might help you](http://officeoneonline.com/vba/events_version.html).

Here's some starter code using the event `OnSlideshowPageChange`

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
    Dim i As Long
    i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition

    Select Case i

        Case 1
            'do something for page one

        Case 2
            'do something for page two

        Case 3
            'do something for page three... etc.


    End Select


End Sub
```